# Best practice to call webservices from Magento custom module

Tags: php, magento, webservice-client

Can anybody tell me, what will be the the best practice to call webservices from a Magento custom module?
Is there any functionality in the Magento / Zend Framework? Or should I use standard PHP functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework provides clients for REST and SOAP webservices.

Check lib/Zend/Rest and lib/Zend/Soap